# How can I log `DEBUG` in lambda via `process.stdout.write`?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

When I am using `console.log` in my nodejs lambda, the log raw data shown in cloudwatch has timestamp as prefix.

For example, `console.log({a:1, b:2}`, will log

```
2020-09-21T13:05:02.312Z\t332c382e-605f-453f-b767-604dd5f542ab\tINFO\t{ a: 1, b: 2 }\n
```

I know that people are talking about using `process.stdout.write` but I don't know how to log `DEBUG` level in the cloudwatch. Everything `stdout.write` will be shown as `INFO`.

Comment: Is your goal to remove logging level prefixes like INFO, DEBUG, WARN ? Could you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 1):

If you follow this example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-logging.html

```js
console.log or console.info (INFO)
console.warn (WARN)
console.debug (DEBUG)
```

I would recommend to use logger libraries like `pino` or `winston` loggers where there is much more control over logging.

Comment: console.log is the one I need to avoid because of the issue in my post. So I am looking for using the stdout.write to remove all prefix.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao Why don't you use a real logger and try to hook there ?

Comment: what do you mean by `real logger`?